# git format-patch includes all files in repo, just want last commit

Tags: git

I'm quite new to git, and pretty new to stack as well, so I apologize if I have trouble formatting my question properly.

I'm attempting to include the two files in my last commit in a patch file.  I've tried this:

```
git format-patch master --stdout> mypatchfilename.patch
```

And this:

```
git format-patch -1 master --stdout> mypatchfilename.patch
```

In both cases, the patch file contains the entire repository instead of just the two files in my last commit.  I haven't been able to piece anything together that works from the doc or tutorials.  How do I just include the last commit in my patch?

Comment: The second command is correct, and works on my machine. What version of git are you running?

Comment: Turns out what I needed was to use the second command with my branch name rather than master.  Apparently, it was putting all of master into a patch file.  (I'm using 1.7.11.mysysgit.0, it says)

Answer (score 0):

For the last commit: `git format-patch --stdout HEAD~1..HEAD` will do. Use `git log --oneline` to get a list of the commits selected so that you can check yourself when making a patch series. Then the changeset selection parameters will be the same when you call the format-patch command. eg:

```
git log --oneline origin/master.. # list changes on current HEAD not on origin/master
git format-patch --stdout origin/master.. # make a patch containing those changes
```

Although I would set the output to a directory and create a set of patches for use with `git am` later on.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  What's the point of HEAD~1..HEAD exactly?  Does it mean the difference between the current version of head and the last version but one?

Comment: Fun fact: You can use `HEAD^!` as shorthand for `HEAD~1..HEAD`.

Comment: Fun fact 2 - on windows, the caret character is used to escape the next character. So HEAD^! ends up as HEAD! when using the cmd prompt which is very annoying hence a tendency to stick to the ~ notation.

Comment: @BobRodes: HEAD~1 means 'the parent of HEAD'. HEAD~2 would be the parent of the parent, and so on. The double dot notation means (A..B) means 'commits on B that are not on A'. So HEAD~1..HEAD is commits that are on HEAD and not on HEAD's parent - ie: the most recent single commit to HEAD (where HEAD is the tip of the currently active branch).